# trying to integrate ajax autocomplete in my create record in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, autocomplete

I found a ajax auto complete and I wan't it to integrate to my form but I can't make it work. Please advise thank you!

[controller]

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Purchasetransactions;
use App\AjaxAutocompleteController;
use App\Products;
use App\Categories;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class PurchasetransactionsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $purchasetransactions = Purchasetransactions::all();
        return view('orders.index', compact('purchasetransactions'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('orders.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $purchasetransactions = Purchasetransactions::create($request->only('products_code','name'));
        return redirect(route('orders.index'));
    }

    /** Auto Complete */
    public function productSearch(Request $request){
        $query = $request->get('term','');
        $products=\DB::table('products');
        if($request->type=='product_code'){
            $products->where('product_code','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
        }
        if($request->type=='product_name'){
            $products->where('name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
        }
        $products=$products->get();        
        $data=array();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $data[]=array('product_code'=>$product->product_code,'name'=>$product->name);
        }
        if(count($data))
            return $data;
        else
            return ['product_code'=>'','name'=>''];
    }

}
```

[create.blade]

```
<div class="container">
        {!! Form::open(array('route'=>'orders.store')) !!}

        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
              <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
              <th>S. No</th>
              <th>Product Code</th>
              <th>product name</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><input type='checkbox' class='chkbox'/></td>
              <td><span id='sn'>1.</span></td>
              <td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type='text' data-type="product_code" id='product_code_1' name='product_code[]'/></td>
              <td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type='text' data-type="product_name" id='product_name_1' name='product_name[]'/> </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger delete'>- Delete</button>
          <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addbtn'>+ Add More</button>
      {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(".delete").on('click', function() {
      $('.chkbox:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
      $('.check_all').prop("checked", false); 
      updateSerialNo();
    });
    var i=$('table tr').length;
    $(".addbtn").on('click',function(){
      count=$('table tr').length;
        var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='chkbox'/></td>";
          data+="<td><span id='sn"+i+"'>"+count+".</span></td>";
          data+="<td><input class='form-control autocomplete_txt' type='text' data-type='product_code' id='product_code_"+i+"' name='product_code[]'/></td>";
          data+="<td><input class='form-control autocomplete_txt' type='text' data-type='product_name' id='product_name_"+i+"' name='product_name[]'/></td></tr>";
      $('table').append(data);
      i++;
    });

    function select_all() {
      $('input[class=chkbox]:checkbox').each(function(){ 
        if($('input[class=check_all]:checkbox:checked').length == 0){ 
          $(this).prop("checked", false); 
        } else {
          $(this).prop("checked", true); 
        } 
      });
    }
    function updateSerialNo(){
      obj=$('table tr').find('span');
      $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
        id=value.id;
        $('#'+id).html(key+1);
      });
    }
    //autocomplete script
    $(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
      type = $(this).data('type');

      if(type =='product_code' )autoType='product_code'; 
      if(type =='product_name' )autoType='name'; 

       $(this).autocomplete({
           minLength: 0,
           source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('productsearch') }}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term : request.term,
                        type : type,
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        var array = $.map(data, function (item) {
                           return {
                               label: item[autoType],
                               value: item[autoType],
                               data : item
                           }
                       });
                        response(array)
                    }
                });
           },
           select: function( event, ui ) {
               var data = ui.item.data;           
               id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
               id = id_arr.split("_");
               elementId = id[id.length-1];
               $('#product_code_'+elementId).val(data.product_code);
               $('#product_name_'+elementId).val(data.name);
           }
       });
    });
    </script>
```

[route]

Route::get('/orders/create','PurchasetransactionsController@create')->name('orders.create');
Route::get('productsearch', ['as'=>'productsearch','uses'=>'PurchasetransactionsController@productsearch']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added multiple autocomplete searches to input fields in laravel, and i've always had to look it back up each time i've implemented it. This is working for me. Here is the input which i'm searching for matching abbreviations in my search

```
 <div class="input-group">
     @if(isset($_GET['variable_name']))
         <input value="{{$_GET['variable_name']}}" type="search" name="variable_name" class="form-control" id="variable_name" autocomplete="off">
    @else
        <input type="search" name="variable_name" class="form-control" id="variable_name" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
   @endif
</div>
```

Script to control ajax return:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    // Set the Options for "Bloodhound" suggestion engine
    var engine = new Bloodhound({
        remote: {
            url: '/find?variable_name=%QUERY%',
            wildcard: '%QUERY%'
        },
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('variable_name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    });

    $('#variable_name').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'abbreviations',
        source: engine,
        display: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data.abbreviation  //Input value to be set when you select a suggestion.
        },
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"><div class="list-group-item">Nothing found.</div></div>'
            ],
            header: [
                '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown">'
            ],
            suggestion: function(data) {
                return '<div style="font-weight:normal; margin-top:-10px ! important;" class="list-group-item">' + data.abbreviation + ' ' + data.table + '</div></div>'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Controller function

```
public function find(Request $request) {

    $result=Abbreviation::where('abbreviation', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('variable_name')}%")
        ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('variable_name')}%")->get();
    return response()->json($result);

}
```

My Route:

```
Route::get('/find', 'PagesController@find')->name('typeahead.search');
```

libraries:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also need the bloodhound.js and tyepahead.jquery