# Laravel JS autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I can't figure out what's going on here. I'm trying to make a pretty simple ajax post to do an autocomplete in laravel.

I have an input box and a spot for the results:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="tag_name" id="tag_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter Country Name" />
     <div id="tagList">
     </div>
</div>
```

and my JS

```
$('#tag_name').keyup(function(){ 
            var query = $(this).val();
            if(query != '')
            {
             //var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
             $.ajax({
              url:"{{ route('campaigns.search') }}",
              method:"POST",
              data:{query:query, _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
              success:function(data){
               $('#tagList').fadeIn();  
                        $('#tagList').html(data);
              }
             });
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
            $('#tag_name').val($(this).text());  
            $('#tagList').fadeOut();  
        });  

    });
```

The route points to my controller function:

```
 public function searchTags(Request $request)
{   

    if($request->get('query'))
    {
        $query = "%" . $request->get('query') . "%";
        $data = CampaignTags::where('TAG_DATA', 'LIKE', $query)->get();

        $output = '<ul>';
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $output .= '<li><a href="#">' .$row->TAG_DATA. '</a></li>';
        }

    }

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

When I inspect as I type, I get 200 codes on the search but I'm not getting actual results to show from the database, the response seems to be null

Comment: Autocomplete shouldn't use POST. By definition it's not changing the state of anything except maybe for logging or analytics purposes, and is instead fetching data. A GET request would therefore be more appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, I've only ever used POST for an autocomplete and that's how I've always seen it done. I thought it had to be post because I'm posting the query data to that endpoint

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed your $query variable. Can you `dd($search)` to see if it's empty. Also can you change to `$request->get('query')` to `$request->query`. @MatthewDaly well theoretically true but doesn't matter in actual practice

Comment: Ah first problem: I have $search in my json encode but it should be $data. That change at least got the whole json object to show

Comment: `return repsonse()->json(['search' => $data]);`

Comment: Where are you getting the search in that example?

Comment: @TomN. No, you can still pass parameters with GET, just they will be passed in the URL. If it's fetching data to populate something, it should usually be GET. Using GET lets you cache responses properly where appropriate, whereas POST should never be cached.

Comment: @senty that doesn't work for me, but return json_encode($data) returns the whole object. I just need the tag_data of the object in my line items

Comment: Like `->pluck('tag_data')`? I don't think I quite understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

I did this using typeahead. and answered it in another thread. before

heres the link. [Auto Complete Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752251/trying-to-integrate-ajax-autocomplete-in-my-create-record-in-laravel/54756555#54756555)